# Possibilities to reduce power consumption with cocos2d apps

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, power-management, heat

I made a board game with includes just some little animations. I reduced the fps from 60 to 30 to reduce the processor load. But the device still gets very warm. 
Another application made without cocos2d is not heating it so much. 
Are there any methods to calm the iPhone down?
The device state is as follows:

- Wifi is always enabled
- The app uses gamecenter
- GPS is inactive
- fps is always on 30
- I use cocos2d-iphone as engine

Comment: Do you use an internet connection? If so often? Do you use openfeint or game center? do you use the gps? do you reduce the fps to 4 when you are not animating.  what game engine are you using (coccos-2d?, raw open gl, core animation?)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth experimenting with different director types, e.g. `kCCDirectorTypeNSTimer`, and seeing if that helps at all. Those will have the biggest effect on the main loop of the game.

You should also spend some time with Instruments if you've not already, as that will show you where the CPU is spending its time and give you some hints on where you could ease things up.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that a sequence of small time animations in cocos2d takes a lot of processor time. I've tried making tips at the level which will pulse in size. 0.1 second pulse up, 0.15 down and 0.2 stay. And i've put it all in a repeat forever sequence. Everything was terribly slow. Then i've just made the animation manually and the device calmed down and fps increased back to 60

Comment: Can you please explain more ? Our game has many `Action` with less than one second duration. How can we fix it ?

Comment: @Emadpres: cocos changed significantly since the last time I used it, so I suggest to profile (there is profiler in xcode) the game and see what is the actual bottleneck. For animations, basically I implemented animations manually in update method of sprite (by switching the frames)

Answer (score 0):

When showing menus or dialogs that do not require animation, you can actually lower your framerate even further.